# roslaunch is not launching all nodes

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, roslaunch, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ros melodic on ubuntu18. I was following the tutorials on tf2, so after going through the broadcaster and listener, the start demo launch file is not launching the listener node.
What is even weirder to me is that it works (without giving an error) when I launch the file directly from the folder i.e.

```
roslaunch start_demo.launch
```

instead of

```
roslaunch learning_tf2 start_demo.launch
```

Here is my launch file

```
<launch>
<node pkg="turtlesim" type="turtlesim_node" name="sim"/>
<node pkg="turtlesim" type="turtle_teleop_key" name="teleop" output="screen"/>


<node name="turtle1_tf2_broadcaster" pkg="learning_tf2" type="turtle_tf2_broadcaster.py" respawn="false" output="screen" >
  <param name="turtle" type="string" value="turtle1" />
</node>
<node name="turtle2_tf2_broadcaster" pkg="learning_tf2" type="turtle_tf2_broadcaster.py" respawn="false" output="screen" >
  <param name="turtle" type="string" value="turtle2" /> 
</node>
<node name="turtle_listener" pkg="learning_tf2" type="turtle_tf2_listener.py" output="screen"/></launch>
```

I have done things like deleting my devel and build folders, running catkin_make, sourcing setup.bash, but still the same issue.
Am I missing something here?
When I run from the folder directly:

```
NODES
  /
    sim (turtlesim/turtlesim_node)
    teleop (turtlesim/turtle_teleop_key)
    turtle1_tf2_broadcaster (learning_tf2/turtle_tf2_broadcaster.py)
    turtle2_tf2_broadcaster (learning_tf2/turtle_tf2_broadcaster.py)
    turtle_listener (learning_tf2/turtle_tf2_listener.py)
```

When I reference through package:

```
NODES
  /
    sim (turtlesim/turtlesim_node)
    teleop (turtlesim/turtle_teleop_key)
    turtle1_tf2_broadcaster (learning_tf2/turtle_tf2_broadcaster.py)
    turtle2_tf2_broadcaster (learning_tf2/turtle_tf2_broadcaster.py)
```

It's the same launch file! What am I missing here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351906/roslaunch-is-not-launching-all-nodes/) by [pravardhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/54760/pravardhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2020-05-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-10**:
It would help if you could show the *verbatim* output of both `roslaunch start_demo.launch` and `roslaunch learning_tf2 start_demo.launch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am sorry, I realized the mistake later. What's happening is that I had another workspace with the same package name and it was sourced last in my bashrc, hence the launch file in that package was getting called which didn't have all the nodes in it. When sourced correctly, it was indeed pointing to the correct launch file and all nodes ran as expected.

---

Originally posted by [pravardhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/54760/pravardhan/) with karma: 38 on 2020-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0